# Cannot match any routes. Angular2 URL with parameters

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular2-routing

I have a `Home` component with a basic form. When the user submits the form, I want to redirect it to `Search` component with some information in the URL.

My **HomeComponent** :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.css']
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {

  worker: string;
  address: string;

  constructor(private router: Router) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  doSearch() {
    this.router.navigate(['/search',  { worker: this.worker, address: this.address }]);
  }

}
```

My **SearchComponent**

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-search',
  templateUrl: './search.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./search.component.css']
})
export class SearchComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) { }

  ngOnInit() {

    let selectedWorker: string;

    console.log(this.route.params); // 
    console.log(this.route.params['worker']); // undefined

   let add = this.route.params
      .switchMap((params: Params) => {

          console.log(params);
          selectedWorker = params['worker'];
          console.log(selectedWorker); //defined


        return null;
      });

    console.log(selectedWorker); // undefined


  }

}
```

And the **routing** module :

```
const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'search', component: SearchComponent },
  { path: 'signup', component: SignupComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
  ],
  exports: [
    RouterModule
  ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

My problem is when I want to retreive the value of the parameters in the `SearchComponent` I get `undefined`. But when I 'console' `console.log(this.route.params);` I found my parameters as below :

[image: Image here]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason that it logs an object in the console is that objects are mutable. It can change somewhere inside your code and the log will print the "most beatiful" version of it.

If you log `console.log(JSON.stringify(this.route.params));` I highly expect if to be undefined again.

The correct way is like the one you did below:

```
let add = this.route.params
     .subscribe((params: Params) => {
       selectedWorker = +params['worker'];
       console.log(selectedWorker); //defined
       return null;
     });
console.log(selectedWorker); // undefined
```

But if you log `selectedWorker` just below it it will be undefined because as you've guessed: route change is an async operation.

Comment: I tested your solution, but it does not work. It gives me undefined even inside the switchMap(). I really don't understand what happen.

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID what does `console.log(params);` log inside the `switchMap`?

Comment: It logs : `{"_isScalar":false,"observers":[],"closed":false,"isStopped":false,"hasError":false,"thrownError":null,"_value":{"worker":"toto","address":"114 bis Boulevard Raymond Poincaré"}}`

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID can you edit your question the way you log this inside switchMap?

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID I asked you to log `params`, you logged `this.route.params`

Comment: Excuse me, I didn't understand. I updated my answer and the log is the same: `{"_isScalar":false,"observers":[],"closed":false,"isStopped"‌​:false,"hasError":fa‌​lse,"thrownError":nu‌​ll,"_value":{"worker‌​":"toto","address":"‌​114 bis Boulevard Raymond Poincaré"}}`

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID I don't think this is true, can you put something in front of it just to make sure it is the log we want? Like `console.log(123, params);` does it log the `123`?

Comment: You are right. Something wrong is happening. It does not console anything. I think the code inside switchMap is not executed.

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID of course not because I think you are testing it wrong. That code will only be executed if the route changes. That is, if the url changes from something else to this components url. Home -> Search for example.

Comment: However, I see the url change in my browser. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID url changes from what to what?

Comment: from `http://localhost:4200/home` to `http://localhost:4200/search;worker=toto;address=dd`

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID that seems correct, btw can you not return `null`? return something like and empty array or something ( `[]` )

Comment: Even by correcting the return value to [], it logs nothing !

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID I've updated my answer. What if you change switchMap with subscribe?

Comment: It works now, thank you very much. But why in the official angular2 documentation siwtchmap is used => https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/router.html#!#optional-route-parameters ?

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID Because switchMap returns an observable(`this.heroes`). And the author of the documentation uses that observable with an async pipe inside the template(`<li *ngFor="let hero of heroes | async"`).

Comment: Ah okay, I missed this part. Thank you very much. You really took time to help me. I appreciate it.

Comment: @RadouaneROUFID no problem, I'm just glad we figured it out :-)